# capture Data from a database with Angular-js to use it for charts and Grahps

Tags: php, angularjs

Yes I have really done my research including all the help from http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/using-with-server-side-languages/php/creating-charts-with-data-from-a-database.html which happened to be the closed to what I needed. however I have failed to make all that I have encountered to work with a live database.

All i need is to be able to dynamically update my Angular-php built Ui charts and graphs using a combination of Angular with php as server side.

some thing like this..
//in some cases i tried google charts thus the dependency injection.

```
angular.module("myCharts", ["ngRoute", "googlechart","ng-fusioncharts"])
.controller('MyController', function ($scope,$http) {

$http.get('scripts/datacall.php')
.success(function (data) {  
  console.log(data); /* this actually shows me the json data in the console. but i just cant print it.*/
  $scope.myDataSource = {
      chart: {
        caption: "My poll results",
        subCaption: "Top ten Candidates",
        numberPrefix: "Vote",
        theme: ""
      }, 
      data: 'data'
  }; // or data:$scope.data

});

});
```

Comment: what's the problem? Unable to visualize the data after you receive the data?

Comment: thank you for your response.  Yes am unable to visualize and plot  the data on graph..

Answer (score 0):

Since you have claimed that you are able to show the data in the console. I believe the problem is binding the data to `$scope.myDataSource`.
The way that you did neither `data:'data'` nor `data: $scope.data` work.

#### First case: `data: 'data'`

You are binding an attribute called `data` to a string value `data`, which is not the data that can draw graphs.

#### Second case: `data: '$scope.data'`

Based on the code you just posted, you did not declare a variable called `$scope.data`. Therefore you will get error and will not be able to draw graphs.

#### How to fix it:

You are using `$http()`with a callback function return data. In this case, you can just binding the data to the `data` attribute, i.e. `data: data`.

```
$http.get('scripts/datacall.php')
    .success(function (data) {  
        console.log(data); 
        $scope.myDataSource = {
            chart: {
                caption: "My poll results",
                subCaption: "Top ten Candidates",
                numberPrefix: "Vote",
                theme: ""
            }, 
            data: data
        };

});
```

Comment: The only pending issue would be displaying the live data as it reaches into the database. I have read around and stumbled upon an un-tested solution with firebase, Angular 3 way data binding. https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-10-04-firebase-angular-data-binding.html when I test it and it fully works am going to come back am mark your answer as full answer. thank you

Comment: @lule75 Does it help you for this problem my solution? If it does, please consider accept or and upvote :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution with following Googles geoCharts an example of the implementation is well elaborated hear. 
https://leachcreative.com/geocharts-drill-and-associated-table/ (example)
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geomap#markers-example

in case the site goes down this was his original Chord but instead of using ajax to load the data i instead loaded it with angularjs. however for three way data binding, I did not get time to mess around with it due to the projects time frame given, but i will come back and update my answer